# School students are instructed, self-taught students [self-study?]

Tags: word-choice, phrase-requests

> "You will be instructed"
>
> "I have been taught for 4 years"

To

> "You will [self-study?]"
>
> "I have been [self-learning?] for 4 years"

Both seem kind of clumsy. Is there a better word or phrase?

Comment: "teaching myself"?

Comment: Self-taught students are self-taught.

Comment: @cornbreadninja麵包忍者 Yeah the title's a little vague but I couldn't think of a better phrasing, I've changed it to be a bit clearer.

Comment: Self-taught students might engage in a _directed study_ or an _independent study_. Typically there is a supervisor involved in these two, but his or her involvement is minimal.

Comment: @longstreth Ah, a form of independent study is a perfect fit for what I have. Add an answer and I'll accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An *independent study* is typically undertaken by a student who teaches himself or herself material with minimal help from a supervisor or instructor. ([Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independent_study) calls it an *"educational activity undertaken by an individual with little to no supervision"*, which works here up to context.) Similar terms include a *self-directed study* or *self-directed learning*. *Autodidacticism* might also work, although that word is longer and perhaps less suited to all situations, as [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/69233/is-autodidact-too-obscure-to-use-in-a-resume) explores.

So you could write

> *You  will study independently*

or

> *I have been engaging in independent study*.

Comment: If the student teaches himself or herself material on his or her own, when he or she is done, does he or she get to keep his or her material afterwards so that it is now his or hers, or is it still the property of the institution through which he or she is or was taking this or that class for himself or herself?

Comment: @tchrist Whoops; looks like I went overboard on the singular pronouns there. This is clearly an unintended consequence of all those independent studies.